# Lower dB to x if it's over 10

Tags: audio

I have an audio track of two persons that are talking to each other, but one of the person sounds very loud and the other person sounds very low. How do I solve this? Can I for example lower the dB of the track whenever it reaches x dB?

Comment: What sort of audio editing software do you have at your disposal? This sort of thing is usually achieved with a compressor or limiter.

Comment: I have none. The only program I have installed that can mess with audio a bit is Sony Vegas. But I guess I can download a program that can do it for me. Audacity seems to be able to do it.

Comment: Yes, Audacity should be able to do it. See http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Compressor

Answer (score 1):

Removing variations in volume between different parts of the same track is usually achieved with a [compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) or [limiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting) (essentially a compressor with a ∞:1 ratio). Many audio editing programs have these tools built-in, [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) is a free one that should be sufficient for your purposes. [Here's the manual for their Compressor effect](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Compressor).

As a general guide, start by setting the threshold above the level of the quiet person, but below that of the loud person. The ratio should be set fairly high, perhaps start with 5:1 or more, depending on how large the difference between the quiet and loud person is, but note that very high ratios tend to introduce artifacts and can sound unnatural. As for attack and release times, 20-30 ms and 100-150 ms, respectively, should be a good starting point. Play around with the settings until the result sounds good, and after that you can amplify the level of the track to make up for any volume loss from the compression.

Comment: For more in-depth information, you might want to ask at [dsp.se] or [sound.se].

Comment: I used the compressor thing and managed to improve the audio a bit, but one of the voices is still too loud. I want the voices dB to be close to equal. Maybe someone can do this for me? The file is 45 minutes long. A .wav file.